# Given a street with lamps, finding minimum cost to light entire street

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here's an exercise I'm struggling with.

A street has *n* lamps, *i*-th lamp is in position *i*.

Initially all lamps are switched off. For the *i*-th lamp you have 3 options:

1. Leave it switched **Off** and pay nothing.
2. Switch it to **Mode 1** and pay *cost1<sub>i</sub>*. The *i*-th lamp will light position *i*.
3. Switch it to **Mode 2** and pay *cost2<sub>i</sub>*. The *i*-th lamp will light the position *i* and *leftRange<sub>i</sub>* more positions to the left and *rightRange<sub>i</sub>* more positions to the right. For example, if *i* = 5, and *leftRange<sub>i</sub>* = 3 and _rightRange<sub>i</sub> = 2, then, switching the light to mode 2 will light positions 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7

I need to find the minimum total cost to light all lamps.
*cost1*, *cost2*, *leftRange* and *rightRange* are all arrays.

Comment: This is a basic exercise in dynamic programming. Here's how you should approach it: If you set light 0 to off, what's the cost of lighting up the rest of the street using the remaining lights? (Think recursion!) Now, if you set light 0 to mode 1, what's the cost of lighting up the remaining street? And with mode 2?

Implemented like a naive recursive function won't work due to the combinatorical explosion, but with dynamic programming it's efficient.

Comment: Can you help me with the code of it maybe pseudo code only. It will help me understand the solution better. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on my own with my baby right now, but I'll give it a shot. I can get interrupted any second :-)

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic exercise in dynamic programming.

I suggest you first transform the arrays into a set of `(interval, cost)` pairs. Then ask yourself:

- What subset of intervals can I use to cover the entire street at the lowest cost?

Reformulate this question into something more recursion friendly as follows:

- What subset of intervals can I use to cover the street **up until index *i*** at the lowest cost?

This question can be answered as follows:

- The cheapest way to cover the street up until index *i* is to use a light that covers *i* PLUS the cheapest way to cover the street up until the left range of that light.

  - The PLUS part can be answered by looking at previously computed costs, since that part is stricly less than *i*
  - Which light to use to cover *i* is determined by iterating over all lights that cover *i* and picking the cheapest one.

When you have this recursive solution in place, simply answer the questions in the following order:

- What subset of intervals can I use to cover the street **up until index 1** at the lowest cost? <sup>(base case)</sup>
- What subset of intervals can I use to cover the street **up until index 2** at the lowest cost? <sup>(computation involves looking at previous answers)</sup>
- ...
- What subset of intervals can I use to cover the street **up until index *n*** at the lowest cost? <sup>(computation involves looking at previous answers)</sup>

Here's a first stab at it:

```
# Sample data
n = 5
cost1 = [ 10, 20, 10, 5, 3 ]
cost2 = [ 15, 25, 10, 10, 30 ]
leftRange = [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 2 ]
rightRange = [ 2, 0, 1, 1, 0 ]

class LightRange:
    def __init__(self, light, mode, left, right, cost):
        self.light = light
        self.mode = mode
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.cost = cost

    def doesCover(self, i):
        return self.left <= i and i <= self.right


# Transform input data into a set of LightRanges
ranges = []
for i in range(n):
    ranges.append(LightRange(i, 1, i, i, cost1[i]))
    ranges.append(LightRange(i, 2, i - leftRange[i], i + rightRange[i], cost2[i]))


# For convenience: Create an index telling us what ranges covers index i
rangesCoveringI = []
for i in range(n):
    rangesCoveringI.append([])
    for r in ranges:
        if r.doesCover(i):
            rangesCoveringI[i].append(r)


# Declare two variables holding our solution:
# costToCoverI[i] = the lowest cost for lighting up the street from 0 to i
costToCoverI = []
# rangeUsedToCoverI[i] = range used for covering i when lighting up the street from 0 to i
rangeUsedToCoverI = []

# Populate the solution variables going from left to right on the street
for i in range(n):
    # Walk through ranges covering i and determine the cheapest one to use
    bestCostToCoverI = None
    bestRangeToCoverI = None

    for r in rangesCoveringI[i]:
        # Compute cost associated with using this range
        costThisRange = r.cost
        costLeftOfThisRange = 0 if r.left <= 0 else costToCoverI[r.left - 1]
        cost = costThisRange + costLeftOfThisRange

        # Cheapest so far?
        if bestCostToCoverI is None or cost < bestCostToCoverI:
            bestCostToCoverI = cost
            bestRangeToCoverI = r
    
    costToCoverI.append(bestCostToCoverI)
    rangeUsedToCoverI.append(bestRangeToCoverI)

# Final solution: costToCoverI[n - 1] = the lowest cost for lighting up the street from 0 to n
print(f"Total cost: {costToCoverI[n - 1]}")

# Backtrack to figure out final mode selection
i = n - 1
while i > 0:
    r = rangeUsedToCoverI[i]
    print(f"{r.light} set to mode {r.mode}")
    i = r.left - 1
```

Output:

```
Total cost: 23
4 set to mode 1
3 set to mode 1
0 set to mode 2
```

N.B.: Untested code.

- Try it out, and try to understand each step.
- Debug any issues you find.
- Ask follow-up questions in the comments if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: can you please elaborate with a pseudo code? i am in hurry my deadline is near

Comment: I suggest: Give it a try yourself based on my answer. Append your question with "UPDATE: This is what I've tried: .... I still don't understand X."

Comment: @AatifRashid, let me know if something in my sample solution is unclear. It was a little bit more complicated than I thought at first, but not that complicated.